# C++ Boost.Serialization - Non intrusive serialization of user-defined members?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I have a class structure like

```
class MemberClass;

class ContainerClass {
  MemberClass special_member;
  int other_members;
};
```

Following the example in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/
i want to write an non-intrusive serialization:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, ContainerClass & c, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & c.other_members; // easy - built-in type
    serialize(ar, c.special_member, version);  //???
}
```

Assuming there's is also a non-intrusive

```
void serialize(Archive & ar, MemberClass & m, const unsigned int version);
```

this compiles and works but i feel this is not the way to do it because it reuses the version number of the container class for the member class?

So how to handle that? Must the Container class manage version of its members individually?

Comment: What is the definition of `ContainerClass`?  Is it something you can change?

Comment: I am not familiar with boost serialization but it looks like the creators of `MemberClass` must also provide a `MemberClass_version` `int` that changes each time `MemberClass` changes and you need to use that one for serialization.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm . Yes, i could change ContainerClass, but i prefer not to do it if possible. I really want to add serialization non-intrusively.

Comment: @bolov. Makes sense. And probably this can be added non-intrusively as well, with the BOOST_CLASS_VERSION macro coming with Boost.Serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that writing

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, ContainerClass & c, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & c.other_members;
    ar & c.special_member;
}
```

Will work just fine, even if we only have the non-intrusive version of

```
void serialize(Archive & ar, MemberClass & m, const unsigned int version);
```

I wasn't aware of that.

You should never explicitly call the external serialize function.